# How to test incremental data in ETL

Tags: sql

I have been asked at many interviews the same question again and again.The question is how would you test incremental data which gets loaded every day in their database.My position is Data warehouse QA plus BA.The main purpose of testing is to check if we have all the data from source and then to test if all the data copied from source got placed in respective tables as designed by developers.

So every time somebody asks this question i answer like this:To test incremental data we take data from staging tables which will have the data for the daily incremental file.So now i can compare the staging table against the target database.Like all databases there might be some calculation or joins we did according to design to get data from staging to production so i will use that design to make my queries to test data in production against source.

So my question here is i have tested incremental loads this way in the only project i did so can anybody give me detailed answer because i think i might not be answering it right.

Comment: What kind of tests are they referring to?  How about "carefully and thoroughly"? ;)

Comment: @GordonLinoff:The main purpose of testing is to check if we have all the data from source and then to test if all the data copied from source got placed in respective tables as designed by developers.Let me know if you need more information and what type of information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incremental loads are inevitable in any data warehousing environment.  Following are the ways to render the incremental data and test it.

1) Source & Target tables should be designed in such a way where you should store date and timestamp of the data (row).  Based on the date and timestamp column(s) you can easily fetch the incremental data.

2) If you use sophisticated ETL tools like informatica or Abinitio, then it is simple to see the status of the loads chronologically.  These tools store the information for every load.  However it has some limitation to store the last 10 loads.  You need to configure it  to store for more than 10 loads.

3) If you are not using sophisticated ETL tools then you should build ETL strategies to store the statistics of the load and capture the information (like no. of inserts, deletes, updates etc.,) during the load.  These information can be retrieved whenever you need.  But it needs lots of technical knowledge to adopt.

If you want to succeed in a data warehouse interview, i would suggest the best iOS application([data-iq](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/data-iq/id588271917?mt=8)) created by a us based company and its for candidates like you . check it out and you may like it.  good luck for your interview.

Answer (score 2):

I will answer it by telling how testing incremental data is different from History data.

1. I need to test only and only the incremental data. So I limit it by using the date condition in my source/staging tables and same date condition or Audit ID used for that incremental load in Target table.
2. Another thing that we need to check while testing incremental data is - Usually in Type 2 tables, we have a condition like

> If a record is already existing in target table and there is no change
> as compared to the last record in target table, then don't insert that
> record.

So to take care of such condition, I need to do a History check where I compare the last record of target table with the first record of incremental data and if they are exactly same then I need drop that record. (Here ACTIVITY_DT is a custom metadata column, so we will look for change only in EMPID, NAME, CITY)

For example - Following are the records in my target table as a part of History load -
[image]

And these are the records which I am getting in my Incremental data

[image]

So In above scenario, I compare the last record of History data (sorted on ACTIVITY_DT DESC) with the first record of Incremental data (sorted on ACTIVITY_DT ASC). There is no change in data columns, so I need to drop the following record as it should not be inserted into target table

> 1 Aashish HYD 6/25/2014

So as part of this incremental load only two records are inserted which are as following -

> 1 Aashish GOA 6/26/2014
>
> 1 Aashish BLR 6/27/2014